# Getting an error when running pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

To isolate my problem I run a simple two line example program that runs fine when using IDLE or other Python environment. However, whenb I try to convert the program to an executable using pyinstaller it comes with an error. The error is shown at the end of the printout. Any help to solve this problem is appreciated.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1110]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\>
C:\>C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pyinstaller example.py
88 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.4
89 INFO: Python: 3.6.5
89 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 124, in run
    spec_file = run_makespec(**vars(args))
  File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 58, in run_makespec
    spec_file = PyInstaller.building.makespec.main(filenames, **opts)
  File "c:\users\John\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\makespec.py", line 664, in main
    with open(specfnm, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as specfile:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\example.spec'

C:\>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Permission denied: 'C:\temp.spec'` is your user allowed to write to the root of the `C:\` drive?

This begs the question why pyinstaller is trying to write (a temp file?) to `C:\` in the first place... is that where your `temp.py` file (that you want to build into an `.exe`) is located??

Try moving `temp.py` to a subfolder of your `My Documents`, etc. and run the pyinstaller command from there.

**PRO-TIP:** if `pyinstaller`'s path is listed in your `PATH` variable, you can call it using only `pyinstaller` (without the full/explicit path)

Comment: Your first question in your reply helped me to solve the problem. I posted the solution below.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. By mistake I used the wrong change directory command and because of that I was trying to run the pyinstaller command from the root folder of my C drive, and I don't have permission with a normal command prompt to write files there.

Wrong reference:

```
C:\>C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pyinstaller example.py
```

Correct reference:

```
C:\Users\Menachem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pyinstaller example.py
```

Answer (score -1):

Please edit your post so we can see the error clearly 
 for the error try to run by administrator cmd if that didn't help check this 
[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51778203/permission-error-when-trying-to-use-pyinstaller)

Comment: `run as admin` as a debugging step is not a secure suggestion IMO, so definitely not as a first step.

Comment: Thank you fo ryoru quick reply. I formatted better the error message. Before I posted my question, I read all the answers in the post that you suggested and it did not help. Note that I run successfuly pyinstaller two weeks ago using my larger program and it worked fine. Now for whatever reason it comes with the same error for the large program and for the example program.