# PermissionError: [Errno 13] when converted to exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable

I have just converted my main python file in my project to an executable and it now returns a permission error when the exe is run. When the source code is run, it works fine. The error message is pasted below:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWgF3.png)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: probably your answer is in [this](https://itsmycode.com/python-permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied/#how-to-fix-permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied-error)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem when receiving permission errors that usually has to do with anti-virus.

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51778203/permission-error-when-trying-to-use-pyinstaller) and it should work. This is the solution that worked for me when I first ran into the same issue with Pyinstaller.

In a CMD or a powershell, enter this below replacing "app_name_here" with what you'd like to name the exe, and replace the example path with your path to the .py file that you're trying to convert.

`python -m PyInstaller --name "App_name_here" "C:\Users\user1\Documents\Python\myapp\main.py`

Comment: I still get the error even using this command format. Here's my command: ...\venv\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe --onefile --noconfirm --windowed --paths "...\venv\Lib\site-packages" --name "STSAS" "...\releases\tester_beta_release_1.0\bin\__main__.py"